# How to prevent an object doing a full rotation on a shaft

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, mechanical, systems-design, prototyping

I basically need a block on a shaft to rotate between 90 degrees (vertical) and approximately 180 degrees (horizontal) counterclockwise on a shaft. I don't want the part to fall below 180 degrees. At 90 degrees it will clip into a stand so clockwise rotation does not need a part preventing rotation. Please advise on a way to prevent clockwise rotation after a certain angle. Thanks :)

Comment: A slot with a pin.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so completely not the best image, but if you have the shaft with a hardened pin fitted - the angular width of the slot can be adjusted to control the angle of rotation and it only needs to match the width of the pin...

[image]